# In IntelliJ IDEA, how to add the same file to multiple version control systems?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

Suppose I have a directory structure like this:

- Root directory (under git)

  - Subdirectory (under hg)
  - Second subdirectory

Then, files in the second subdirectory will correctly be committed to git and files under the first subdirectory to hg, but I would *also* want files in the first subdirectory to be committed to the root git repository, and I would prefer not to add the files manually each time they're updated.

Is that possible?

Comment: `Subdirectory` should be updated into `git` unless you have included in `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as:

- you do a `git add .`  from `Root directory`
- you don't have ignored `Subdirectory` (check that with a `git check-ignore -v --  Subdirectory\afile`)
- but you have ignored `Subdirectory \.hg`

You should be in one command (again `git add .`) add *all* modified files.
And that applies with an IntelliJ project in `Root directory`: its Git plugin will see both subfolders as regular data for Git to manage.